# Dynamic generate method value

Tags: c#, dynamic, methods

This code will help me generate labels in this sequence e.g

> A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
>   B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
>   D1 D2 D3 D4 D5

But now what i want is that i can click on the label, every label will have their own ID and call a method to check is free to use. 

So i need to let it auto generate the bold part

```
vartable[namelabel].Click += new System.EventHandler(**vartable[namelabel]_Click**);
```

namelabel is auto generate same as the name or the

```
Private void lbl11_Click
```

What can i do?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            for (int q = 1; q <= 9; q++)
            {
                string lettle="a";
                if(i==1)
                {
                    lettle="A";
                }
                else if(i==2)
                {
                    lettle="B";
                }
                else if (i == 3)
                {
                    lettle = "C";
                }
                else if (i == 4)
                {
                    lettle = "D";
                }
                else if (i == 5)
                {
                    lettle = "E";
                }
                else if (i == 6)
                {
                    lettle = "F";
                }
                else if (i == 7)
                {
                    lettle = "G";
                }
                else if (i == 8)
                {
                    lettle = "H";
                }
                else if (i == 9)
                {
                    lettle = "I";
                }

                string labeltext = lettle + q;
                int y = (100 + (q * 20));
                int x = (100 + (i * 20));
                string namelabel = "lbl" + i + q;
                var method = namelabel;
                   var vartable = new Dictionary<string, Label>();
                    vartable[namelabel] = new Label();
                    vartable[namelabel].AutoSize = true;
                    vartable[namelabel].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(y, x);
                    vartable[namelabel].Name = namelabel;
                    vartable[namelabel].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
                    vartable[namelabel].TabIndex = 1;
                    vartable[namelabel].Text = labeltext;
                    vartable[namelabel].Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
                    this.Controls.Add(vartable[namelabel]);
                    vartable[namelabel].Click += new System.EventHandler(**vartable[namelabel]_Click**);



            }

        }
```

Comment: the question is not precise and too broad. Consider to describe what you want to do more clearly that a reader unfamiliar with your project knows what you want to achieve in order to help you.

Comment: I'm actually doing something like booking a theater seat,so when i click the label, it will allow me or not allow me to book the seat. I have let it auto load the place which is taken away. so if this seat is taken away, it will turn red, while if its adaviable it will turn blue. But whenever it click, it should still counter check and show booked or being taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the "Tag" property of Label (inherited from base class Control) to store the seat number. This allows you to use the same event handler for all Label objects. Once the event handler gets called, it can determine by inspecting Tag which Label actually has been clicked.

The booked/available information could be stored in an array of booleans indexed by the seat number.

Sample event handler:

```
 private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((Label)sender).Tag.Equals("1"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Label 1 clicked!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm quite new to C#, how to inspect which label is being click? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for asking so many question, the Tag.Equals("1")) the "1" is it mean the name of the label? My label name is name from lbl11 to lbl99.

Comment: "Tag" is a property of every Control object. You can assign any Object to Tag. In my sample, I have assigned a String "1" to Tag using the Visual Studio Property Editor. You could equally well check the "Name" property to distinquish the Label objects from eachother.

Comment: i actually do this
if((((Label)sender).name to retrive my label name that is click.
thanks!